# Too Much System Time

Tags: system-calls, strace

I have observed that when running CESM (a weather modeling application), the `top` command shows a great deal of time is spent on system calls, about 25% to 60%, and only 40% to 75% is used in user code. The application does some I/O and communicates with MPI.

A sample output from the top command is given below:

```
top - 16:54:32 up 11 days, 13:45,  2 users,  load average: 8.12, 8.25, 8.08
Tasks: 201 total,   9 running, 192 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 74.3%us, 25.2%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.5%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  24659792k total,  5259280k used, 19400512k free,  1747768k buffers
Swap: 28667984k total,   234408k used, 28433576k free,   169080k cached

  PID USER    PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
20748 user1   25   0  516m 304m  26m R 100.2  1.3  22:31.81 ccsm.exe
20750 user1   25   0  497m 293m  26m R 100.2  1.2  27:12.45 ccsm.exe
20754 user1   25   0  496m 290m  24m R 100.2  1.2  27:18.33 ccsm.exe
20751 user1   25   0  496m 291m  25m R 99.9  1.2  27:21.63 ccsm.exe
20752 user1   25   0  496m 291m  25m R 99.9  1.2  27:18.97 ccsm.exe
20749 user1   25   0  686m 446m  26m R 99.2  1.9  26:36.16 ccsm.exe
20753 user1   25   0  554m 335m  25m R 98.5  1.4  27:19.78 ccsm.exe
20755 user1   25   0  496m 289m  23m R 97.2  1.2  27:12.34 ccsm.exe
```

Using the `strace` command to attach to process 20748 shows a lot of

```
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}], 7, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}], 7, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=4, events=POLLIN}, {fd=5, events=POLLIN}, {fd=6, events=POLLIN}, {fd=7, events=POLLIN}, {fd=10, events=POLLIN}, {fd=18, events=POLLIN}, {fd=19, events=POLLIN}], 7, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
```

Using `strace -c -p 20748` to count time for a while I got:

```
$ strace -c -p 20748
Process 20748 attached - interrupt to quit
Process 20748 detached
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 85.17    0.068864           0  11713876           poll
  9.74    0.007876           2      4208           write
  4.45    0.003595           1      6463           munmap
  0.37    0.000302           0      6463           mmap
  0.22    0.000179           0      1068           brk
  0.03    0.000025           1        18           open
  0.02    0.000016           1        18           read
  0.00    0.000000           0        18           close
  0.00    0.000000           0         2         1 stat
  0.00    0.000000           0        18           fstat
  0.00    0.000000           0         2           madvise
  0.00    0.000000           0         1           getcwd
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00    0.080857              11732155         1 total
```

The file descriptors appeared in the poll are sockets and a pipe.

```
4 -> socket:[2789396]
5 -> socket:[2789451]
6 -> socket:[2789452]
7 -> socket:[2789456]
10 -> pipe:[2789492]
18 -> socket:[2789517]
19 -> socket:[2789518]
```

I feel too much time are wasted in poll and wander if anything can be done to decrease this. The first thing I can think of is to find where `poll` is called. The code of the application doesn't call `poll` directly. How can I trace back to the source of the call? How to trace back to where the sockets are created?

Answer (score 2):

The time in `poll` is not wasted - it is the time the process waits for input data to "arrive" or for output buffers to be ready for new output data.

You can use `lsof` to list the open descriptors (including sockets).

How many CPU cores do you have in the system?
How many cores can ccsm use?

Your `top` listing shows around 100% CPU usage for ccsm.exe processes.
It seems to me that your bottleneck is not I/O but the CPU.

Anyway, to reduce the "poll time" you would need to speed up I/O - for example by putting the data (database?) on a fast mass memory (system).

Comment: Each node has 8 cores and ccsm is using multiple full nodes.

Comment: What should I look into from the output of lsof? I think you mean my bottleneck is not the CPU but I/O, right? Are the sockets used for MPI communications or something else? Since there is no disk files involved, can I assume the disk I/O is not an issue?

Comment: I think your bottleneck is the CPU. The `strace` profile just shows the time spent in system calls. How long did it run until you interrupted it? You need to divide the times from `strace` output by that time: part of the time spent for IO = 0.0688 s / total s * 100%